# Transparent Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make a nav bar on my website that is being transparent on the header and then after scrolling it's color changes to a certain color and i wrote some js code in order to reach that but in my case , i have a small problem that when i scroll on page and return to header the nav bar doesn't return transparent any more and still with the color, transparent only at launch or refresh

```
   <script>    
    var x = document.getElementById("navy");
    window.onscroll = function(){
        if(document.body.scrollTop >= 200)
        {
            x.classList.add("transparent")
            x.classList.remove("scrolled")
        }
        else
        {
            x.classList.add("scrolled")
            x.classList.remove("transparent")
        }
    };
   </script>
```

Comment: Use the browser's dev tools to add a breakpoint inside the callback and inspect the values and go through it step by step, maybe `x` was modified somewhere else (personally I would define `x` inside the callback)

Comment: @arieljuod Good tip thank u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/L561fzdj/

```
var x = document.getElementById("navy");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if(window.pageYOffset >=100){
        x.classList.remove("transparent");
      x.classList.add("scrolled");
    }
    else{
      x.classList.add("transparent");
      x.classList.remove("scrolled");
    }
}, false)
```

Comment: Thank U very much that's exactly what i need thank u sir ^^

Answer (score 1):

First off all you want it to be transparent when you return to the header so your if else statements are already in the wrong order.

```
        if(document.body.scrollTop >= 200)
        {
            x.classList.add("scrolled") //when its >= 200 it means the user is 
            x.classList.remove("transparent") //scrolling downwards
        }
        else
        {

            x.classList.add("transparent") //so I swapped your classes for you
            x.classList.remove("scrolled")
        }
```

Second of all, document.body.scrollTop is not the end all be all to check for users' scroll positions, I find that using a mix of a few commands like in skrollr's source works very well for me.

```
Skrollr.prototype.getScrollTop = function() {
        if(_isMobile) {
            return _mobileOffset;
        } else {
            return window.pageYOffset || documentElement.scrollTop || body.scrollTop 
                   || 0;
        }
    };
```

Here is the github link on the source code : https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/b98d40820b9864be275e81af382045d72cc5a08a/src/skrollr.js#L627